# Change connector type in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

Connector type change from elbow to curved or curved to connector is needed. But Excel is not recording the changes happening in shapes, tried all object properties, Can someone help?

Comment: Types are here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834664.aspx

Comment: Thanks Tim, i dont want to add connector of particular type, instead i want to change the connector type of existing connector in excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860918.aspx

E.g.

```
activesheet.shapes(3).connectorformat.type = msoConnectorCurve
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, i was looking for his past 3 Hrs, ur solution is really helpfull